# Problem overwriting navigator.languages in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a problem that I can't solve, to finish making anonymous puppeteer.
So far I have passed all the anti-bot tests, but I can't configure the language, let me explain:

- Overwriting the user agent, I manage to change the "navigator.language" from "en-US, in" to "es-ES, es"
- But I have tried everything and I am not able to overwrite the "navigator.languages" it always remains in "en-US, en"

I hope there is someone who can help me change the languages.

I attach screenshots and link of the plugin I use.

https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth

https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/blob/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth/evasions/user-agent-override/index.js

---

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");


// add stealth plugin and use defaults (all evasion techniques)


const stealth_plugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");
const stealth = stealth_plugin();

puppeteer.use(stealth);

const UserAgentOverride = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth/evasions/user-agent-override");

const ua = UserAgentOverride({locale: "es-ES,es;q=0.9", userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/537.36", platform: "MacIntel"});

const path = require('path')
const websites = require('./websites.json')

async function run() {
    puppeteer.use(ua);

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        userDataDir: "./cache",
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        ignoreDefaultArgs: [
            "--disable-extensions",
            "--enable-automation",
        ],
        args: [
            "--lang=es-ES,es;q=0.9",
            "--no-sanbox",
            "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
            "--disable-gpu"
        ]
    })

    console.log(await browser.userAgent());
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    const pathRequire = path.join(__dirname, 'src/scripts/index.js')
    for (const website of websites) {
        require(pathRequire)(page, website)
    }

}

run().catch(error => { console.error("Something bad happend...", error); });
```

Image of anti bot test results:

[image: Image of anti bot test results]

---

Hi there
Thanks for the answer, after testing the edited code, I have noticed the following:

- when I launch the browser, once any url is entered, the configuration disappears.
- however if I don't put any url, it passes the test perfectly.

And even without putting url it is well configured, I attach two images one with url and one without, I don't understand what I can do and I have tried everything.

Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors (navigator.languages)

```
it's writable using the languages evasion:

[value] => en-US
[writable] => 1
[enumerable] => 1
[configurable] => 1

while it should be
configurable: false
enumerable: true
value: "es-ES"
writable: false
```

[Image of anti bot test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm7Zm.png)

[Image of anti bot test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iab4k.png)

Comment: Hi @vsemozhebuty,
Thanks for the answer I am attaching an issue in case you are interested in discussing it, it keeps bringing me upside down.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 You would be so kind to help me, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I had not any answer for your issue, I've just fixed some formatting. I hope somebody more experienced will help.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Thank you very much for the support and attention, greetings.